# XAMPP/Apache error: VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage

Tags: apache, xampp

While using Apache on XAMPP my localhost keeps failing to load. It'll work for a bit and then it'll just stop working. First I got this error about increasing my ThreadsperChild option (which I did, to 1500) but now I keep getting these errors:

"VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.
Can't initialize heap: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address."

Either that, or (depending on what value I choose for the ThreadsperChild option, e.g. 800,400,1500 etc.) I only get: "AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name"

In either case the localhost won't load. I'm using Mozilla Firefox to try to reach the localhost. It used to work fine but then XAMPP/Apache just started giving me all these errors.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there an ideal number for the ThreadsperChild option or is there something else in the config files that needs to be changed? It's really frustrating because the localhost will host a test file first no problem and then the next file I try to load will not come up and the server becomes unresponsive. It must be a simple fix but I just can't seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably out of memory. Threadsperchild is way to high. Every Thread at least needs a stack, which by default under Windows is 1MB, so 1500 would be a minimum of 1.5GB per worker process, let's assume you have like 5 worker then that's 7.5GB gone for nothing. Set the number lower and try to solve the other error when you set it lower